# open_basedir 制限の解除

Tags: php, .htaccess

PHP スクリプトを実行しようとしたら下記のエラーが出てきます：

```
WARNING: is_readable() [function.is-readable]: 
    open_basedir restriction in effect.
    File(/usr/share/php/Am/View/Helper/HeadScript.php) is not within the
    allowed path(s): (/home/1205915141/members-net/:/tmp:/usr/share/pear/)
    in line 198 of file 
    /home/1205915141/membersnet/public_html/library/Zend/Loader.php
```

サーバーの管理者に聞いたら、open_basedirをセキュリティ上変更ができないといわれて、こっちでhtaccessを使って下記のように解除しようとしていますが、だめのようです。

```
php_value open_basedir  /usr/share/php/
```

パスが間違ってるか、書き方自体が間違ってるか分かりませんが、どうしてもうまくいかないので教えていただければ幸いです。

Comment: .htaccess で「php_admin_value open_basedir none」とするとどうなりますか？

Comment: お返事をどうもありがとうございます。残念ながらまだ同じエラーが出ます。

Comment: 了解です、お手数をかけましてすみません。

Comment: いえいえ、とんでもないですよ。

Answer (score 2):

`php_value` ではなく `php_admin_value` を使用してみてください。

```
php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/php/
```

ご参考: PHP: コア php.ini ディレクティブに関する説明 - Manual http://php.net/manual/ja/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

Comment: お返事をどうもありがとうございます。残念ながら、そうすると５００エラーが出てきました。

Comment: では `.htaccess を使っての設定はできないようですね。 `/home/1205915141/membersnet/public_html/library/Zend/Loader.php` が `/usr/share/php/` 配下を見に行かないように変更するのがよいかと思います。

Comment: PHPスクリプト自体をいじるってことですか？

Answer (score 2):

共有サーバーなどでしょうか？
使いたいファイルやライブラリを全て自分で管理できるディレクトリに配置してください。

Htaccessなどで設定できる内容とそうでない内容はphpのマニュアルに掲載されています。
該当の項目は管理者がシステム単位でしか設定できないSystemレベルかと思います。

スクリプト、フレームワーク、ライブラリなど扱う全てのファイルが権限チェックの対象になっています。
共用のディレクトリのファイルを読み込まないように設定やプログラムを変更してください。

Comment: 共有サーバーですね。public_htmlに配置してますが、やはりphp.iniの設定がユーザー側でできないようになっていますからhtaccessを使うという手を考えましたが、それでもだめのようです。

Comment: ライブラリをご自身のディレクトリに配置しフルパスで指定すれば読み込めるはずです。探索順の変更は可能ですがまずはフルパスでどうぞ

Comment: ライブラリといいますと、library/Zend/Loader.phpなどのことですか？

Answer (score 1):

利用されている PHP のバージョンは 5.3.0 未満でしょうか？

open_basedir は 5.3.0 未満だと PHP_INI_SYSTEM なので .htaccess で変更することはできません。

http://php.net/manual/ja/ini.core.php#ini.sect.path-directory

httpd.conf で php_admin_value で指定すれば大丈夫かもしれませんが、共有サーバだとそれもできないでしょう。

---

5.3.0 以上でも .htaccess などで緩い方に設定を変更することはできないと思います。

Comment: バージョンが5.3.3のようです。仰る通り、共有サーバーなのできません。

Comment: 追記しました、5.3.3 でもダメそうです。

Comment: そうですか。そうしたらこちらでphp.iniを作って読み込むとかは？

Comment: それも httpd.conf を弄らなければ無理かと思います。

Comment: そうですか。でしたら全く手つけられないということみたいですね。